# トランプのカードをすべて表示する方法

Tags: python

現在pythonを学習しています。
トランプのカードをすべて表示したいのですが、rm_cardメソッドを定義する理由がわかりません。
どなたか教えてください。

```
from random import shuffle

class Card():
    suits = ["spades", "hearts", "diamonds", "clubs"]
    values = [None, None, "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7","8",
              "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"]
    def __init__(self, value, suit):
        self.value = value
        self.suit = suit

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.values[self.value] + " of " + self.suits[self.suit]

class Deck():
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
        for i in range(2, 15):
            for j in range(0, 4):
                self.cards.append(Card(i, j))
        shuffle(self.cards)

    def rm_card(self):
        if len(self.cards) == 0:
            return
        return self.cards.pop()

deck = Deck()

for card in deck.cards:
    print(card)
```

Comment: ladleさんご回答ありがとうございます。理解することができました！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

そのプログラム(War Game)の完全版は [self_taught/python_ex280.py](https://github.com/calthoff/self_taught/blob/master/python_ex280.py/) になります。「rm_cardメソッドを定義する理由」は、このゲームにおける必要な処理(deck からカードを一枚取り出す)だから、です。

Answer (score 0):

> トランプのカードをすべて表示する方法

質問の趣旨とは異なりますが、リスト内包表記を使ったコード例です。

```
from random import shuffle
suits = ["spades", "hearts", "diamonds", "clubs"]
values = ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"]

cards = [(suit, value)for suit in suits for value in values]
shuffle(cards)
for suit, value in cards:
    print(value + " of " + suit)
```

[入門Python 3](https://iss.ndl.go.jp/books/R100000002-I026914699-00)を参考にしました。